# Docksal and Git shallow issue

Tags: docksal

When I set up a docksal project, it uses git and the project folder ends up with a remote:

```
https://github.com/docksal/boilerplate-drupal9-composer.git
```

I then add another remote, to the repo for the codebase I am developing.

The problem is that the clone done by docksal was shallow, and when I try to push to my repo the push is rejected because of the shallow setting (the *shallow* file in .git)

Comment: Git is behaving correctly (i.e., as designed). If you don't want a shallow clone, don't use `--shallow` when cloning. How to get some *non*-Git software to do that is not a Git question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to drop the .git folder and initialize a fresh git repo in the project folder Docksal created.

In case you'd prefer to inherit the boilerplate git repo commit history, you can always clone the repo directly:

```
git clone https://github.com/docksal/boilerplate-drupal9-composer.git drupal9
cd drupal9
fin project start
```